# MVC formcollection not getting value set by jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

On a button click, With Jquery, i am checking some validations & setting a value to Hidden Field & then control is redirected to HTTPPOST. 
I am not able to get this value in formcollection.

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="hdnField" id="hdnField" />
```

Jquery

```
function validate(){
  ....
  jq("#hdnField").val("somevalue");
}
```

Controller

```
HTTPPOST
form["hdnField"].ToString() is getting blank.
```

All the basic things are correct such as form collection object as i am getting other values of form.

If i do Inspect Element then value is seen to be set correctly to the hidden field.

What is causing this?

Comment: Can you post some more code . It will help in not recreating the whole scenario in my dev environmment

Comment: have you created {get, set} for your hdnField property